# Dialog cannot be applied

Tags: android

Estou tentando usar uma Dialog mas a seguinte mensagem aparece
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue meu código

```
package com.example.gustavo.vigilantescomunitarios;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TabRua extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_rua, container, false);
    }

    public void abrirMensagem(View view){
        final Dialog dialogMensagem = new Dialog(this);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Obs:** A classe Dialog é a classe de base para caixas de diálogo, mas você deve evitar instanciar Dialog diretamente. Em vez disso, use uma das subclasses a seguir:
>
> [AlertDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html?hl=pt-br), [DatePickerDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html?hl=pt-br) ou [TimePickerDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html?hl=pt-br)
>
> Recomendação que a própria *Google* faz na [documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html?hl=pt-br) do *Android*.

**Context**

> Interface que contém informações globais sobre um ambiente de aplicação, é uma classe abstrata cuja implementação é fornecida pelo *Sistema Android*, ele permite o acesso a recursos específicos do *aplicativo*, além de chamadas para operações de nível de aplicativo, como atividades de lançamento, intenções de transmissão e recebimento, etc.

Alguns *Objetos* e *Componentes*  precisa de um *Context*, você precisa informar para eles o que está acontecendo.

Você pode usar o método `getActivity()`

```
final Dialog dialogMensagem = new Dialog(getActivity());
```

**AlertDialog**

Para utilizar a classe *AlertDialog* você sempre fara a instância da classe *AlertDialog.Builder*, mas porque ? A classe *AlertDialog* não permite por padrão que classes de diferentes pacotes consigam instanciá-la, porém, ela nos disponibiliza a classe estática e interna *Builder* que recebe um *Context* como parâmetro e que nos devolve o próprio objeto, ou seja, podemos chamar mais de um método ao mesmo tempo. Então se tentar:

```
AlertDialog dialogo = new AlertDialog();
```

Irá retornar um erro de compilação. Em vez disso faça:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
// Utiliza o método setTitle() para definir um titulo
dialogo.setTitle("Meu diálogo");
// Utiliza o método setMessage() para definir uma mensagem
dialogo.setMessage("Mensagem do diálogo.");
// Para exibir, use o método show()
dialogo.show();
```

Ou você pode fazer tudo isso em apenas uma tinha:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Meu diálogo").setMessage("Mensagem do diálogo.").show();
```

Veja a [documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html?hl=pt-br) para saber mais sobre a classe *AlertDialog.Builder*

Comment: A sua resposta sairia valorizada se explicasse o porquê do erro e porque não se pode usar o this.